# Как увеличить значение переменной, в цикле while?

Tags: python, дата, datetime

Код:

```
s_d = datetime.date(12)            
ed = datetime.date(11)              
s_d = 10       





while start_date < end_date:                    
    s_d += s_d
    t_l = start_date - s_d
    c_t = s(t_l) + str(s_d)
    print(f"{c_p}")
```

Что в терминале:

```
1976-04-05 - 1977-03-30
1977-03-30 - 1978-03-24
```

Как увеличить значение переменной `start_date`, после ее сложения с шагом даты?
Операция сложения `s_d += s_d = 1977-03-30.`
Эту дату `1977-03-30` мне нужно забрать и увеличть ее значение на 1 день(прибавить к ней 1 день), и так на каждом кругу цикла вайл.
Пробовал разные решения, но во всех вариантах решения цикл уходит в бесконечность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставьте в самом конце цикла `start_date += plus_den`:

```
while start_date < end_date: 
    # ...
    print(f"{chto_proishodit}")
    start_date += plus_den       # <- вот эта строка добавлена
```

Вывод:

```
1976-04-05 - 1977-03-30
1977-03-31 - 1978-03-25
1978-03-26 - 1979-03-20
...
```

Comment: Благодарю, за вашу помощь !